# How do I set a permanent trigger for a cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Example]

In this image, the live price will increase and decrease periodically. How do I set triggered to "yes" permanently if live price = trigger price even once?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(200>=205; "yes"; "no")
```

and substitute `200` & `205` with respective cells

Comment: apologies for less clarity in the question. please check out the edited question.

Comment: @SatyajitKumthekar that would be possible only with script